# flask_restful import Resource error

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I did the following tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_ht4AKnWZg

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'about':'Hello World!'}

    def post(self):
        some_json = request.get_json()
        return {'you sent': some_json}, 201

class Multi(Resource):
    def get(self, num):
        return {'result': num*10}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(Multi, '/multi/<int:num>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now when I run the script, I get following error:

```
/home/one/systemx/test_api$ python flask_restful.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask_restful.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_restful import Resource, Api
  File "/home/one/systemx/test_api/flask_restful.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_restful import Resource, Api
ImportError: cannot import name Resource
```

The code is 1:1 like in the video. Does someone have a idea where the problem is?

Comment: Do you have any files called `flask_restful`, it maybe cause a clash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments by @tobey, you need to rename your program to something else like `app.py` because python is trying to find `flask_restful` and it finds your program instead of the package.

Answer (score 0):

**These installations worked for me**

```
aniso8601 = "==8.0.0"
click = "==7.1.2"
flask = "==1.1.2"
flask-restful = "==0.3.8"
flask-sqlalchemy = "==2.4.3"
itsdangerous = "==1.1.0"
jinja2 = "==2.11.2"
markupsafe = "==1.1.1"
pytz = "==2020.1"
six = "==1.15.0"
sqlalchemy = "==1.3.18"
werkzeug = "==1.0.1"
```